# http charging high volume of http requests

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, httprequest

Sorry for banal question, but i would like to know, while i launch many many http requests to a site, will  site goes down or just i will be banned after n request limit (according to server settings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is most always the case the answer is: *it depends* :)

Now, seriously, it depends on a few things but most likely if you're just hitting "a" server with a single client computer you most likely will not be able to make it *go down* as servers usually have more bandwidth (networking & processing powers) available to them than most client computers. Plus, when you're making requests to a website you might actually be making requests to a load-balanced network of servers which definitely means that a single client will not be able to outperform the *site*. If this is the case your IP will probably get blacklisted or maybe just ignored.

The other possibility is to make a lot of requests with a number of different clients at the same time - using different IPs. This is what is usually called a coordinated or distributed **denial of service attack**. In that case you *might* be able to make the web server(s) *go down* for a while.

This is just a simple answer but I hope you get the point.